# How to change Ghostscript output file (in printer spooler)

Tags: ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript to print a PDF by command line arguments. But it shows the printed document's name as Ghostscript output in printer spooler. I want to change it to a custom name (as letter's name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose you must use a `setup.ps` file as in [this link](http://ghostscript.com/doc/7.07/Devices.htm#BJC_PPD) under section: 6.2 Supported options (device properties)

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to the documentation in http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.06/Devices.htm#Win

In particular there is an example in section 10.2 with explanation of the parameters that can be specified in section 10.3. Just changing the document name can be done by:

```
mark /UserSettings <</DocumentName (MyDocName)>> (mswinpr2) finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice
```

This can be put into a file as in the example, or can be in a string on the command line **following** a `-c` option. If you use -c instead of putting the above PostScript in a setup file, put it in as the last option before `-f` and the input-filename.

**Note:** You should **not** specify the `-sDEVICE=mswinpr2` on the command line -- the **setdevice** takes care of this. I tested this on my laptop with the command line:

```
gswin32c \
  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH \
  -c "mark /UserSettings <</DocumentName (MyDocName)>> (mswinpr2) finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice" \
  -f examples/colorcir.ps
```

Comment: hi...

This i have Used earlier but this solution having a problem .

Output page size comes as letter only even if i use -sPAPERSIZE 

Thanks

Comment: but still the outputpaper size is "LETTER"

Comment: I guess this is a bug in Ghostscript, either sources and/or config files.

Answer (score 3):

If the `sPAPERSIZE` switch is ignored, perhaps it is possible to force the page size
by using the appropriate switches.

The
[How to Use Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm)
manual says in the section
[Choosing paper size](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Paper_size):

```
Otherwise you can set the page size using the pair of switches

    -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=w -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=h 

Where w be the desired paper width and h be the desired paper height in points (units of 1/72 of an inch).
```

The section
[Appendix: Paper sizes known to Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Known_paper_sizes),
the A4 size is defined as
w=595 and h=842.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*This provides a partial solution to the issue, which is perhaps acceptable for your needs.*

The options to control the output size are (markdown inserts spaces, but there should be none):

1. `-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=`*`w`*, `-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=`*`h`*
   (w,h=595,842 / 612,792 for A4 / letter, respectively), [Ref](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Use.htm#Paper_size).
2. `-sPAPERSIZE=`*`size`*, [Ref](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Use.htm#Paper_size).
3. `-g`*`number1`*`x`*`number2`*
   (number1,number2=5953,8419 / 6120,7920 for A4 / letter, respectively), [Ref](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Use.htm#General_switches).
4. `-dDEVICEWIDTH=`*`number1`*, `-dDEVICEHEIGHT=`*`number2`*
   (number1,number2=5953,8419 / 6120,7920 for A4 / letter, respectively), [Ref](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Use.htm#General_switches).

I have tested the four of them, printing a pdf file to pdf, trying to convert (letter -> A4) and (A4 -> letter).
The command line I used is

```
gswin32c -dPDF -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dFIXEDMEDIA <size setting flags> -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

A4 -> letter always worked well.

letter -> A4 only worked for the width, so `output.pdf` was always 210mm x 279.4mm.

Using, e.g., `-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS` alone for letter -> A4 produced the same result.

Adding flag `-dPDFFitPage` was also useful for partially adapting size (in cases I want to do that).

My conclusion is that there is some bug in Ghostscript specifically related to letter -> A4 conversion. Whether this could be handled via `gs_setpd.ps` (e.g., [this](https://ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-devel/2008-May/007776.html); this would still be a bug), or a crafty combination of (`-dUseBleedBox`, `-dUseTrimBox`, `-dUseArtBox`, `-dUseCropBox`) I don't know.

Comment: Thank you. I have also tried those switches, without success. Couldn't be the solution in the locale settings or some other setting? I'm using Windows 10. When the document is printed from Acrobat Reader it works well. [Here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm) is written `On Windows and some Linux builds, the default paper size will be selected to be a4 or letter depending on the locale.`

Comment: I'm rewarding the bounty for this complex answer, although it still does not work.

Comment: @xralf - Your comment points to `gs_init.ps`... it may be worth a try. It seems not that hard changing the locale to something that one would think (or otherwise have it documented) gives A4 as a default. From what I read, and without any support other than gut feeling, I guess it won't work.
Since it seems you would very much like to have that feature, I guess it is worth filing a bug.

Comment: @xralf - Is any of the weak workarounds of any use for you, anyways?

Comment: I already tried to set `gs_init.ps` but without success. Your answer telling how it should work and with pointing to bug is certainly very useful.