# printer settings don't change (winapi: documentproperties)

Tags: delphi, winapi, printing

Language: delphi 6

I succeeded in opening the dialog using documentproperties.

However, I changed the settings and clicked OK, but it does not change.

I want to change the paper to A3.

Please tell me how to do it.

code:

```
var
   FPrinterHandle:THandle;
   aDevice: array[0..255] of char;
   DevMode: PDeviceMode;
   StubDevMode: TDeviceMode;
   DeviceMode: THandle;
begin
   strpcopy(aDevice, Combobox1.Text);
   if OpenPrinter(aDevice,FPrinterHandle,nil) then begin
      DeviceMode := GlobalAlloc(GHND, DocumentProperties(self.handle, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, StubDevMode, StubDevMode, 0));

      if DeviceMode <> 0 then begin
        DevMode := GlobalLock(DeviceMode);
        DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, DevMode^, DevMode^, DM_OUT_BUFFER);

        DevMode^.dmFields := DM_PAPERSIZE;
        DevMode^.dmPaperSize := DMPAPER_A3;
        DocumentProperties(0, FPrinterHandle, ADevice, DevMode^, DevMode^, DM_OUT_BUFFER or DM_IN_BUFFER);

        GlobalUnlock(DeviceMode);
        GlobalFree(DeviceMode);
      end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Can't you do this using [`TPrinter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Printers.TPrinter) (the [`Printer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Printers.Printer) identifier in unit `Printers`)?

Comment: I want to print an external file (PDF).
However, I don't know how to print an external file as a printer object.

Comment: I will change the default printer settings and print using 'shellexecute'.

Comment: Well, I realise now that it might not be possible using `TPrinter` anyway...

Comment: ShellExecute (Handle, 'print', PChar (Pchar (path)), nil, nil, sw_hide); This will print to default printer. So I want to change the default printer settings (ex. Paper, tray, etc.) in the program.

Comment: Open the PDF file with the default program and let the user print it from there or get a PDF lib that can print directly.

Comment: Or try to open the PDF file with a ``TWebBrowser`` (or add ``Chromium`` to your app, e.g.) and print from there

Comment: PDF printing using shellexecute prints fine without problems. What I want is that I want to do the printer settings in the app, not in the control panel (cmd: control printers) before printing.

Comment: If you want to change the *default* settings of the printer: I'm not sure it's a good idea, but if you really want to do it, the first thing to do is check the return value of `DocumentProperties()`.

Comment: In fact, after reading the documentation of [DocumentProperties()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/documentproperties), it seems that it can't change the default settings.

Comment: Oh .. TT .. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could try Ghostscript, it allows to select the paper size (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014636/ghostscript-how-to-set-custom-page-size-using-command-line) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61139152/12763954)). Just make sure you use the `-dFIXEDMEDIA` flag.

Comment: Did you try to use any external printing tools? And one more thing... why are you using Delphi 6?

Comment: Even if the default setting has not been changed, the setting has been changed within the program so that it is printed as A3 or A4. Reference: https://stackoverrun.com/ko/q/1742980

Comment: Try to use [`SetPrinter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/setprinter) after calling `DocumentProperties`: "If you use `SetPrinter` to modify the default `DEVMODE` structure for a printer (globally setting the printer defaults), you must first call the `DocumentProperties` function to validate the DEVMODE structure."

Comment: And There is a sample: [Changing Settings Using the SetPrinter Function](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132365/Configuring-Printer-Settings-Programmatically): `GetPrinter` > `DocumentProperties` > `SetPrinter`

Comment: Hi, did you solve the issue? If so, could you please share the solution and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) yourself.

Comment: See the link in my comment. I will also put the answer. [link](http://stackoverrun.com/ko/q/1742980)

Answer (score 1):

## It's not the code I wrote, it's from somewhere. Hope it helps.

Pass the printer name and desired paper size as parameters. (I used GetPrinter procedure)

If parameter(integer) is 0, it is set to A3, and if it is 1, it is set to A4.

And when I printed pdf file with shellexecute, I checked that it prints in the desired size.

※ Before print, the tray of the printer should be set to 'automatic selection'.

```
procedure SetPrinterInfo(APrinterName: PChar; Psize: Integer);
var
  HPrinter : THandle;
  InfoSize, BytesNeeded: Cardinal;
  DevMode: PDeviceMode;
  PI2: PPrinterInfo2;
  PrinterDefaults: TPrinterDefaults;
begin
  with PrinterDefaults do
  begin
    DesiredAccess := PRINTER_ACCESS_USE;
    pDatatype := nil;
    pDevMode := nil;
  end;
  if OpenPrinter(APrinterName, HPrinter, @PrinterDefaults) then
  try
    SetLastError(0);
    //Determine the number of bytes to allocate for the PRINTER_INFO_2 construct...
    if not GetPrinter(HPrinter, 2, nil, 0, @BytesNeeded) then
    begin
      //Allocate memory space for the PRINTER_INFO_2 pointer (PrinterInfo2)...
      PI2 := AllocMem(BytesNeeded);
      try
        InfoSize := SizeOf(TPrinterInfo2);
        if GetPrinter(HPrinter, 2, PI2, BytesNeeded, @BytesNeeded) then
        begin
          DevMode := PI2.pDevMode;
          DevMode.dmFields := DevMode.dmFields or DM_PAPERSIZE;
          if Psize = 0 then DevMode.dmPaperSize := DMPAPER_A3
          else if Psize = 1 then DevMode.dmPaperSize := DMPAPER_A4;
          PI2.pSecurityDescriptor := nil;

          // Apply settings to the printer
          if DocumentProperties(0, hPrinter, APrinterName, PI2.pDevMode^,
                                PI2.pDevMode^, DM_IN_BUFFER or DM_OUT_BUFFER) = IDOK then
          begin
            SetPrinter(HPrinter, 2, PI2, 0);  // Ignore the result of this call...
          end;
        end;
      finally
        FreeMem(PI2, BytesNeeded);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    ClosePrinter(HPrinter);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I think it doesn't help to open the dialog via 'documentproperty procedure'.

Comment: Oh, and if you go into the printer properties, it doesn't seem to have changed to A3, but it's changed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution and you could also [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)