# Ghostscript.net Printing PDF Name in Spooler

Tags: vb.net, pdf, printing, ghostscript.net

when I print a PDF file by

```
Public Sub PrintViaGS(PDFFile As String)
    Using processor As New GhostscriptProcessor()
        Dim switches As New List(Of String)()
        switches.Add("-empty")
        switches.Add("-dPrinted")
        switches.Add("-dBATCH")
        switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE")
        switches.Add("-dNOSAFER")
        switches.Add("-dPDFFitPage")
        switches.Add("-dNumCopies=1")
        switches.Add("-dQUIET")
        switches.Add("-sDEVICE=mswinpr2")
        switches.Add(Convert.ToString("-sOutputFile=%printer%") & PRINTERNAME)
        switches.Add("-f")
        switches.Add(PDFFile)
        processor.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), Nothing)
    End Using
End Sub
```

everything works fine.. but the name displayed in the Printer's Spooler is wrong! It's displayed as "Ghostscript output"
Where can I change the name?

Thanks!!

Lubo

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348864/how-to-change-ghostscript-output-file-in-printer-spooler

Comment: @Lubo Did you end up figuring this out? I'm having the same issue...