# How to change Ghostscript output file (in printer spooler) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess, ghostscript

I'm trying to print a pdf file with `ghostscript` in `Python3`.
I tried to write [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12355635/653379) code in Python.

```
os.chdir(documents_dir)
file = "myFile.pdf"
args = '"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\gs\\\\gs9.52\\\\bin\\\\gswin64c" ' \
       '-dBATCH ' \
       '-dNOPAUSE ' \
       '-dFitPage ' \
       '-sOutputFile="%printer%{}" ' \
       '-c "mark /UserSettings <</DocumentName ({})>> (mswinpr2) finddevice putdeviceprops setdevice" '.format(ptr_name, file)
ghostscript = args + os.path.abspath(file)
subprocess.call(ghostscript, shell=True)
```

It should print `myFile.pdf` so that in the printer spooler will be shown `myFile.pdf` as the job name.

How can I fix that command?

When the `ptr_name` is `Microsoft Print to PDF` the program ends up silently with empty PDF file.
When I used another `ptr_name` it ended with this error message

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's only a partial message, missing all the important text, and ite very hard to read. Rather than posting a picture of the text why not post the actual text (all of the back channel) ?

I don't speak Python, so how about stating (or indeed printing out) the contents of 'ghostscript' from your program (I'm assuming this is a string variable of some type). That would be useful for you too since it would let you see what your are tring to run and can look for errors in the string or syntax.

Clearly, if the command line works from the shell, there must be some difference in the command you are sending from Python.

Comment: There was a space in the file name.